# When to use mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

When should i use mysql_real_escape_string?

Is it only when i'm inserting rows into a database?  Or only when i have user input?

Thanks

Comment: A good resource already on here on sql injection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: The best I can tell `mysql_real_escape_string` may stop SQL injections at the cost of a buffer overflow. The function does not take a destination buffer size, so it relies on oversized strings and nice attackers who won't use "too many" escapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use mysql_real_escape_string() whenever you're building a query that will be run against the database. Any user input that is being used to build a database query should be run through this function. This will prevent sql injection attacks.

User inputs are your big area of concern when it comes to this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use mysql_real_escape_string when you are inserting the value of a string into an SQL statement, and you are using the MySQL API.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE foo = '" . $foo . "'";
```

Should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE foo = '" .
        mysql_real_escape_string($foo) . "'";
```

However you should also consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with prepared statements and bind parameters  instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`. This reduces the risk of errors.

Answer (score 0):

always, apart from integers, there you use `intval()`

Answer (score 0):

It will simply filter all special character which included in form data to prevent from SQL injection(SQL injection is a hacker tool for hacking website through some queries with form data}